# stemgraphic returning wrong numbers

Tags: python, plot, distribution

The following code doesn't seem to be working properly.

```
from stemgraphic import stem_graphic
stem_graphic([1,2])
```

[image]

This is wrong.  The stem and leaf plot should show

```
0|2
0|1
```

How can I get the correct result?  I understand the numbers on the far left are the cumulative count.

Comment: The [documentation](http://stemgraphic.org/doc/Quickstart%20with%20number.html) shows it producing a "key", which you haven't reproduced in your question. If the key indicates that 20 => 20 * 0.1 = 2.0, as in the linked example, then this output is correct. In other words, I think you're misinterpreting the output rather than that you've found a bug.

Comment: As @pjs noted, key is 20, so what you see is what you've got, no bug.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is based on a misunderstanding, not a bug or programming issue.